# python lxml: how to return xml child node with parent tag?

Tags: python, lxml

The original XML as:

```
<POLST>
    <PO>
        <PONo>0000-001</PONo>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <PONo>0000-002</PONo>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <PONo>0000-002</PONo>
    </PO>
</POLST>
```

My Python Code as:

```
from lxml import etree

posxml = '''
<POLST>
    <PO>
        <PONo>0000-001</PONo>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <PONo>0000-002</PONo>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <PONo>0000-002</PONo>
    </PO>
</POLST>
'''

root = etree.fromstring(posxml)

for target in root.xpath('/POLST/PO')[0:2]:
    print(etree.tostring(target))
```

The output as:

```
<PO>
    <PONo>0000-001</PONo>
</PO>
-------------------------------
<PO>
    <PONo>0000-002</PONo>
</PO>
```

How to modify the python code to output with parent tags as:

```
<POLST>
    <PO>
        <PONo>0000-001</PONo>
    </PO>
</POLST>
-------------------------------
<POLST>
    <PO>
        <PONo>0000-002</PONo>
    </PO>
</POLST>
```

In fact, we have too large PO XML and want split into one PO each file.

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: full code is updated.

Comment: `root1 = etree.Element("POLST")`
`root1.append(target)`
`print(etree.tostring(root1))` this will do the job if added to the for loop